# How to Collapse data with weighted averages for the variables?

Tags: dataset, multilevel-analysis, stata

I have a dataset containing postal codes, district numbers and some other variables such as income, age, education levels etc from about 10,000 observations. I need to Collapse(mean) variables 'income' and 'age' by postal codes but I want to take the weighted average so that I avoid the following problem.

After collapsing, I find the average income and age by postal codes amongst my observation. However, not all observation are evenly spread out by postal codes. There are more observations from 1 postal code as compared to another, which is normal. However for collapsing, I want to reweight my variables in such a way that proportionately more weight is given to postal codes with more observations and less to postal codes with lesser observations.

This way the average income and age by postal code would not be unbiased. If somebody could help me out with any tricks or solutions, it would save a lifetime of effort from me.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by using analytics weights (aka aweights in Stata) in your analysis of the collapsed/aggregated data:

> analytic weights are inversely proportional to the variance of an observation; that is,
> the variance of the jth observation is assumed to be
> $\frac{\sigma^2}{w_j}$, where $w_j$ are the weights. Typically, the
> observations represent averages, and the weights are the number of
> elements that gave rise to the average. For most Stata commands, the
> recorded scale of aweights is irrelevant; Stata internally rescales
> them to sum to N, the number of observations in your data, when it
> uses them.

Here is a toy example:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 automobile data)

. sum price

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
       price |         74    6165.257    2949.496       3291      15906

. collapse (mean) price (count) w = price , by(foreign)

. list, clean noobs

     foreign     price    w  
    Domestic   6,072.4   52  
     Foreign   6,384.7   22  

. sum price [aw=w]

    Variable |     Obs      Weight        Mean   Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
       price |       2          74    6165.257   201.8417   6072.423   6384.682

. sum price

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
       price |          2    6228.552    220.8003   6072.423   6384.682
```